# What is the algorithm to add binary numbers with boolean operations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, boolean-algebra

What is the algorithm to add up two binary numbers using only boolean operations (negation, conjunction, disjunction) in linear time? Also the program flow needs to be "linear" as well, meaning there can only be assignments involved (no branching).

---

One example of such program would be Karatsuba's algorithm for multiplying two numbers. Here's the algorithm:

```
x = a * 2^(n/2) + b

y = c * 2^(n/2) + d

z = x * y = (a * 2^(n/2) + b) * (c * 2^(n/2) + d) = ac * 2^n + (ad + bc) * 2^(n/2) + bc

u = (a + b) (c + d)

v = a * c

w = w * d

z = v * 2^n + (u - v - w) * 2^(n/2) + w // result
```

Example:

```
x = 1011, y = 1101

u = (a+b)(c+d) = 101 * 100

v = 10 * 11 = 110

w = b * d = 11 * 01 = 11

z = 110 * 2^4 + (10100 - 110 - 11) * 2^2 + 11 = 10001111
```

Converting to base ten we would have $z = 143$, which agrees with $x\cdot y = 11\cdot 13$.

---

With addition we can just `XOR` everything but I have no idea what to do with the carry, because the 1's won't be contiguously going one after another.

As an example:

```
x = 101, y = 111

z = (x & ~y) OR (~x & y) = 101 XOR 111 = 010
```

We can try to get the carry by doing `x & y`. Then we would get `101` but need to get `11`.

Comment: What on earth do you mean by "when the basis is in linear time"???

Comment: @barakmanos I think he means that he wants a linear time addition algorithm using those three operations, given the binary expansion of the two numbers as input. But that's just a guess.

Comment: @Arthur: In either case, there is zero effort shown in the question, and of course, no response to either one of the comments here, which makes it futile to put any effort attempting to understand the question at hand (let alone to answer it).

Comment: @barakmanos so much hostility. I am just looking for something like Karatsuba's algorithm, except for adding, not multiplying

Comment: @paulpaul1076: I apologize, no hostility meant. But you need to put some effort into your question if you're expecting others to put effort in answering it.

Comment: @barakmanos what more effort do you need? This is how the question goes. I need to write a linear(and linear time) program to add 2 binary numbers using negation, conjunction and disjunction.

Comment: What barak manos wants is for you to have tried a few things on your own, and tell us about them.

Comment: First of all, as already noted in the comments above, your description is not clear. If you can clarify it, then please do it **within the question**, and not in a comment. Second, please share you thoughts, progress and general effort made towards solving this problem on your own.

Comment: how does it matter what I have and have not tried? the main point is that I haven't achieved the goal. @barakmanos you are the only person that complained about not understanding the question.

Comment: 1. Read @Arthur's comment below mine. 2. It does matter what you've tried, read the website guidelines for posting a question here.

Comment: @barakmanos I described Karatsuba's algorithm with an example, I need the same but for adding, not multiplying and I can only use disjunction, conjunction and negation

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/40754/755.  Please don't cross-post on multiple SE sites; that is forbidden by site rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds like a simple adder with carry.

If $x = (x_{N-1} \cdots x_0)_2$, $y = (y_{N-1} \cdots y_0)_2$ then 
$z = x + y = (z_p \cdots z_0)$ via

\begin{align}
z_0 &= (x_0 + y_0) \bmod 2 \\
    &= X_0 \dot{\vee} Y_0 = (X_0 \wedge \neg Y_0) \vee (\neg X_0 \wedge Y_0) \\
c_0 &= X_0 \wedge Y_0 \\
z_{k+1} &= (x_k + y_k + c_k) \bmod 2 \\
        &= (X_k \wedge \neg Y_k \wedge \neg C_k) \vee
           (\neg X_k \wedge Y_k \wedge \neg C_k) \vee
           (\neg X_k \wedge \neg Y_k \wedge C_k) \vee
           (X_k \wedge Y_k \wedge C_k) \\
c_{k+1} &= (X_k \wedge Y_k \wedge \neg C_k) \vee
           (X_k \wedge \neg Y_k \wedge C_k) \vee
           (\neg X_k \wedge Y_k \wedge C_k) \vee
           (X_k \wedge Y_k \wedge C_k)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks man, I don't know why I got stuck on this, I thought I couldn't use any iteration whatsoever, but having thought this through, I guess this is what my prof meant, thanks.

Comment: This should need a constant of ops times the bit length, so $O(N)$. I tried to model what the usual hardware does and this requires only a constant number of gates. So modulo mistakes I hope this works.

Comment: Yep, exactly what I needed, wish I could upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Your objective, clarified through reasonable assumptions, is not possible. Any algorithm that uses only bitwise operations (I am assuming negation is meant to be bitwise negation), will act the same on corresponding bits regardless of their values. So, if both leading bits are zero and need to end up being one, while both lowest bits are zero, the algorithm will either send (0,0) to 1 and incorrectly set the low bit to one, or it will send (0,0) to 0 and incorrectly set the high bit to zero. This can be mitigated with constants, but any fixed algorithm uses constants of a limited size, and the same argument applies to inputs which have zeros in all bits which are set in any constant.

In real computers, a major method of taking into account bit values is to shift the bits left or right by a certain amount. So, I will add a left or right shift of one to your available base operations. After a left shift of one, the bit with value $2^{k+1}$ is set iff the bit with value $2^k$ was set before the shift, and the low bit is zero. Likewise, after a right shift of one, the bit with value $2^{k-1}$ is set iff the bit with value $2^k$ is representable in the width being used and it was set before the shift.

Also, without any loops or recursion, you will have a constant time algorithm which of course cannot handle arbitrarily large integers. I will use a single conditional recursive step for clarity, but this could easily be replaced with a loop. One way or another, you need control operations for arbitrary addition to be possible.

For your question to make sense, there needs to be a set width representation of the numbers being used. Otherwise, negation will have an infinite or ill defined output. If the width is set absolutely, then any algorithm will be constant time and incapable of arbitrary addition, so assume the width $k$ is set to one greater than the width of the largest input, so as to ensure the output is representable. The following is a possible algorithm under these assumptions, where $x<<1$ means "$x$ left shifted by one" and $x>>1$ means "$x$ right shifted by one", and $k$ and $m$ are the inputs. $x\wedge y$ and $x\vee y$ represent conjunction and disjunction, respectively.

Write the sum discarding carry-overs to $x$ and the carry-overs rightshifted by 1 to $y$:
$x = -k$
$y = -m$
$x = x\wedge y$
$y = k\wedge m$
$x = x\vee y$
$x = -x$

Add in the carry-overs:
if (y!=0){
$z = x>>1$
$y =$ ADD($z,y$)
$y = y<<1$
$x = x\wedge 1$
$x = x\wedge y$
}

A couple notes are in order. $x\vee y=-(-x\wedge -y)$ and $x\wedge y=-(-x\vee-y)$, so conjunction and disjunction are redundant with regard to your apparent objective of a minimal base. Also, the requirement of only assignments is superficial. Any operation can be written out that way using intermediate variables. For example, $x=f(g(y),h(z))$ can be sequenced as $v=g(y)$, $w=h(z)$, and $x=f(v,w)$.

This is not meant to be the most efficient algorithm, it is only intended to demonstrate the kind of things that can be done to build an algorithm like this out of simpler operations. It is, however, easy to verify that the algorithm uses base operations with number bound by a multiple of the input width.

Comment: >> is not a boolean operation, so this doesn't answer my question

Comment: Read my first paragraph, there is no algorithm that answers your question as you stated it.

Comment: This is one of the questions I got in my complexity analysis class. I don't think I'd purposely get something impossible. I get your point, though. But I'm pretty sure if I asked the same about multiplication when Katsuba hadn't yet discovered this, you'd be saying the same thing.

Comment: What I said was a proof, not an opinion. The algorithm you are asking for does not exist any more than a proof that 2+2=6. If this was a question from your class, either your professor is mistaken or you have not presented it correctly. Something that goes beyond bitwise operations is necessary, or else a fixed width is necessary so that you can use constants to distinguish each bit.

Comment: The input size of both x and y is N bits, so it is a fixed size

Comment: Running time of an algorithm only makes sense if the input can be infinite. If there is a bound on the input then the running time is constant, in that it is bounded by the constant equal to the largest running time in the finite list of running times for the possible inputs. So, the assumption I made in my answer is probably what your teacher wants, take arbitrary input and treat it as represented in a certain number of bits, then your algorithm needs to be linear in the number of bits used.

Comment: The input is 2 N bit numbers and the time should be linear, O(n), I thought it's obvious.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding big $O$ notation. $O(n)$ means bound by a constant multiple of the input length $n$. If there are 2^32 possible inputs, no matter what the algorithm is, there are 2^32 possible running times. If T is the maximum of these, then the algorithm is bound by $T*n$. So all algorithms are linear if the input is bounded. I suggest you read up on big $O$ before you try solving a problem using the principal.

Comment: From what you are saying you don't understand the difference between time and resource complexity.

Comment: What I have said should make it clear that any bounded input algorithm runs in $O(1)$. This conversation is not constructive, so I will not elaborate, but I warn you that you do not understand big $O$ notation, you should be aware of that for your class.

Comment: Once again, you don't understand the difference between time and resource complexity, you should read on that a little bit before trying to explain it.

Comment: And just for future reference, don't post post things you don't understand. You might get downvotes.